# Inner, outer, and total automorphism of $Spin$ groups

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, representation-theory, lie-groups, automorphism-group

The center Z$(G)$, the automorphism group Aut($G$), the outer automorphism Out($G$) and the inner automorphism Inn($G$) are related. They form short exact sequences:
$$
1 \to \text{Z}(G) \to G \to \text{Inn}(G) \to 1, 
$$
$$
1 \to \text{Inn}(G) \to \text{Aut}(G) \to \text{Out}(G) \to 1,
$$
and a combined exact sequence
$$
1 \to \text{Z}(G) \to G  \to \text{Aut}(G) \to \text{Out}(G) \to 1.
$$
If $G$ is a simply-connected compact Lie group and ${\bf{g}}$ is its Lie algebra (necessarily semi-simple),
then
$$\text{Inn}(G)=\text{Inn}({\bf g})=\mathrm{P}G \text{ (the projective group) },$$
$$\text{Aut}(G)=\text{Aut}({\bf g}),$$
and
$$ \text{Out}(G)=\text{Out}({\bf g})= \text{Aut}(D_{{\bf{g}} })$$
is isomorphic to the automorphism group of the Dynkin diagram $D_{{\bf{g}} }$ of the Lie algebra ${\bf{g}} $.

### My question

What are the inner, outer, and total automorphism groups of $Spin$ groups? Say $Spin(n)$ for any positive integer $n$?

1. For $G=Spin(1) = \mathbb{Z}/2$, the $\text{Z}(G)= \mathbb{Z}/2$, $\text{Inn}(G)=0$,  $\text{Out}(G)=0$, and $\text{Aut}(G)=0$, correct?
2. For $G=Spin(2)=U(1)=S^1$, the $\text{Z}(G)= G=U(1)$, $\text{Inn}(G)=0$,  $\text{Out}(G)=\mathbb{Z}/2$, and $\text{Aut}(G)=U(1)$, correct?
3. For $G=Spin(3)=SU(2)=S^3$, the $\text{Z}(G)= G=\mathbb{Z}/2$, $\text{Inn}(G)=PSU(2)=SO(3)$,  $\text{Out}(G)=0$, and $\text{Aut}(G)=PSU(2)=SO(3)$, correct?
4. For $G=Spin(n)$ with $n \neq 8$ and $n =0 \mod 4$  but $n>3$, the $\text{Z}(G)= \mathbb{Z}/2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}/2=(\mathbb{Z}/2)^2 $, $\text{Inn}(G)=PSpin(n) \equiv\frac{Spin(n)}{(\mathbb{Z}/2)^2}=\frac{SO(n)}{\mathbb{Z}/2}$,  $\text{Out}(G)=\mathbb{Z}/2$, and $\text{Aut}(G)=PSpin(n) \rtimes \mathbb{Z}/2=\frac{SO(n)}{\mathbb{Z}/2} \rtimes \mathbb{Z}/2$, correct?
   *How exactly is this semidirect product $ \rtimes$ defined?*
5. For $G=Spin(n)$ with $n \neq 8$ and $n =2 \mod 4$  but $n>3$, the $\text{Z}(G)= \mathbb{Z}/4$, $\text{Inn}(G)=PSpin(n)\equiv\frac{Spin(n)}{\mathbb{Z}/4}$,  $\text{Out}(G)=\mathbb{Z}/2$, and $\text{Aut}(G)=PSpin(n) \rtimes \mathbb{Z}/2=\frac{Spin(n)}{\mathbb{Z}/4} \rtimes \mathbb{Z}/2$, correct? *How exactly is this semidirect product $ \rtimes$ defined?*
6. For $G=Spin(n)$ with $n =1,3 \mod 4$ but $n>3$, the $\text{Z}(G)= \mathbb{Z}/2$, $\text{Inn}(G)=PSpin(n)\equiv\frac{Spin(n)}{\mathbb{Z}/2}=SO(n)$,  $\text{Out}(G)=\mathbb{Z}/2$, and $\text{Aut}(G)=PSpin(n) \rtimes \mathbb{Z}/2=SO(n) \rtimes \mathbb{Z}/2$, correct? *How exactly is this semidirect product $ \rtimes$ defined?*
7. For $G=Spin(8)$, the $\text{Z}(G)= \mathbb{Z}/2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}/2$, $\text{Inn}(G)=PSpin(8)=SO(8)$,  $\text{Out}(G)=S_3$, and $\text{Aut}(G)=SO(8) \rtimes S_3$, correct? **How exactly is this semidirect product in $SO(8) \rtimes S_3$ defined?**

(Note that $\pi_1(Spin(n=1))=0$, $\pi_1(Spin(n=2))=\mathbb{Z}$, $\pi_1(Spin(n \geq 3))=0$.)

Comment: **Corrections**: In fact, $\pi_1(\mathrm{Spin}(2))$ is $\mathbb{Z}_2$ not $\mathbb{Z}$, as you even point out that $\mathrm{Spin}(2)\cong S^1$. That means of course that $\mathrm{Spin}(2)$ is not the universal cover of $\mathrm{SO}(2)$, which is an exceptional case. Your $\mathrm{Aut}\,$s are wrong for $\mathrm{Spin}(2)$ and $\mathrm{Spin}(3)$; you're missing the duality automorphisms that yield $\mathrm{Out}=\mathbb{Z}_2$ for both of these. Your $\mathrm{Out}\,\mathrm{Spin}(4)$ is also incorrect, which is another special case.

Comment: I am confused, isn that Out(Spin(3))=Out(SU(2))=0? So similarly Out(Spin(4))= Out(SU(2)xSU(2))=Z2 instead? Thanks!

Comment: Can you give some references? E.g. for $Out(G)=Aut(D_g)$. Do I understand correctly that in this list you computed first $Out(G)$ and then $Aut(G)$?